# SumIF() Returning 0 Even If I manually Sum() It Is > 0

Tags: excel, excel-2013, worksheet-function, sumifs

I want to match the value in `Sheet1!A` to `Sheet3!A` and where they match `SUM()` the matching values in `Sheet2!B`

I tried this formula, but it is returning a 0 value even when a manual count returns > 0.

What did I set-up incorrectly in this formula?

```
=SUMIF(A:A,Sheet3!A:A,Sheet3!B:B)
```

Comment: Your criteria is an entire column which may be throwing it off.

Comment: @BruceWayne -> Even if I modify it to hold actual cell values, I am still getting 0's returned where I should not =SUMIF(A2:A86,Sheet3!A2:A2089,Sheet3!B2:B2089)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Sheet3!A:A,$A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),Sheet3!B:B))
```

If you column A is numbers and not text change the `"zzz"` to `1E+99`.

---

Edit

By you comments put this in the first cell:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet3!A:A,A2,Sheet3!B:B)
```

And copy down.

Comment: this will actually return a number, but the counts are inflated

Comment: What do you mean inflated?

Comment: For example, for the first 4 this is what is returned using your formula 343
342
341
340
332
331
 - but if I do a filter and manually sum, they return 1, 4, 8, 10

Comment: Sheet1 will contain a name -> John for example.  On sheet 3 I want to find all isntances of John in column A and SUM() the number that is in column B so I can see the total items sold by this sales person

Comment: This formula returns the total sum in one cell not line by line totals.  You need to provide test data and expect outcome.

Comment: The updated formula solved it. Thank you so much @ScottCraner